# How to make temporary un-hit-testable paths in paper.js?

Tags: paperjs

I need to make temporary paths (which will get removed once some operation is completed) using paper.js but I do not want them to be available in the [HitResult](http://paperjs.org/reference/hitresult).

I can achieve this by adding [a flag to such paths](http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#data), have a wrapper function over HitTest api which removes such paths from the result.

But I do not think this is a good design. HitTest calculations can be sped up if such paths are ignored at initial stages.

Is there any other option to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the item as `locked` to skip it in the `hitTest` calculations.

```
var path = new Path.Circle(new Point(100, 70), 50);
path.fillColor = 'black';
path.locked = true;

function onMouseDown(e) {
  console.log(e.item);
}
```

And a Sketch [here](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/NY69CoMwFIVf5ZJFBRE7lBZLJ7sWCh1rhzRea0i8V2Ksg/juTQrdzg8f56yC5ICiEneDXvUiF4rb6D/SwSh9D2cgXOAWZFFrpyymP8+afLoryxwOZZbDvsxODUWg6LS1NVt2AU1eViqT/CvLymAbcu9mDGFD3UzKayZguvI84YUXSjGDtSEAxTSxxYC9Uyy0xyGObJELR18OpRnjj0lUD3EUz+0L)

Quoting this [thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/paperjs/-B4z-9kgGxE/Bc32upnQDNAJ):

> For now it only affects `Item#hitTest()`. Any item that is locked is skipped there.